# Display unicode triangles (arrows) in Android

Tags: android, unicode, arrows

I've seen the following question ([Javascript encoding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586430/javascript-encoding-question)) to get unicode triangles (arrows) to be displayed. In android 4.4.4 I've tried to use \u25B2 and \u25BC in an alert dialog's radio group list, but these arrow characters aren't displayed. The \u25B4 and \u25BE arrows work but these arrows are too big. I really need to use \u25B2 and \u25BC. I've downloaded the app "Unicode Map" from Google Play and these characters are not shown as well. Is this a limitation in the android version? I've tested in android 5.0.2 and it works.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a font issue.  If you want to use those characters in your UI, you have to make sure a suitable font is installed/embedded to support them.